# update render in unity 3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm a totally beginner with unity and I'm trying to follow a tutorial from a book using unity 2017.1f1. However, I get a problem when I came to the line after the "//", because it appears an error in Unity that says An object reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent()'. Any ideas how to correct it?

```
public class LaunchBall : MonoBehaviour
    {

    public Vector3 launchBallHome = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f);
    public float lbSpeed;
    public bool checkLBToggle = true;
    private Color lbColor;
    Renderer rend;
    bool lbJump;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        gameObject.transform.position = launchBallHome;
        lbSpeed = 0.1f;
        lbColor = new Color(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
//
        rend = GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        lbJump = true;
    }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: It's not an "obsolete command.". It's a simple typo by you. It should be `gameObject` **not** `GameObject`. The `gameObject` is an already declared variable while `GameObject` is a class. Again, `GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>()` should be `gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>()`.  Closed as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Programmer said,

```
 GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

You are trying to get the component renderer from the GameObject Class. 
What you instead should do is:

```
 gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

Which would get the component renderer of the gameobject the script is attached on.

Note: GameObject is a Class. gameObject is a variable which references to the gameobject the current script is attached on.

Comment: I don't see the need to answer question with just a typographical error since simply replacing "G" with "g" should fix it. The comment section should be used to help OP and the question closed. By the way, this question won't be helpful to anyone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

`GetComponent<T>()` is an instance function. If you want to get a component on a game object, simply call this method on the **instance** of that object in your scene.

In your example, it seems like you simply want to get a reference to a component on the same game object. Well there's nothing simpler than that, simply use

```
rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

Regarding the 'obsolete command' I believe you're confusing with the default `renderer` property on every game object. It is indeed obsolete and will at some point be removed. However it doesn't look like you're using that property, which is good.

Comment: I don't see the need to answer question with just a typographical error since simply replacing "G" with "g" should fix it. The comment section should be used to help OP and the question closed. By the way, this question won't be helpful to anyone in the future.